# UWP Message Popup

Tags: c#, uwp

In an UWP app, I can get the MessageDialog to open when I use in a button click event like the code below:

```
 private async void TestBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a MessageDialog
        var dialog = new MessageDialog("This is my content", "Title");
        // If you want to add custom buttons
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Click me!", delegate (IUICommand command)
        {
            // Your command action here
        }));
        // Show dialog and save result
        var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
```

But when I try to call the same event handler in a for loop, I see nothing in my app.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            TestBtn_Click(null, null);
        }
```

I want the app to pause, and display some data like the Console.ReadLine() does.

Comment: I guess your loop does not execute on the UI thread. use the invoke pattern.

Comment: Can you share some more code from where this for loop is executed? because as per your code I don't see there's any issue unless you are running those for loop in some background thread as @dlatikay suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your return type from **void** to **Task** which will make the message dialog to await.

```
// your function
private async Task TestBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

// where you call
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
  await TestBtn_Click(null, null);
 }
```